# How to write ClickHouse OVER statement in DolphinDB?

Tags: clickhouse, dolphindb

I have a query in ClickHouse with the following syntax:

```
avg(ask) over(partition by sym order by time asc rows between 13 preceding and 0 following)
```

How can I write a DolphinDB script that can achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Grouping Logic:

`partition by` is replaced by `context by`

In DolphinDB, you can use keyword `csort` after `context by` to substitute for the ClickHouse’s `order by time asc`.

- Windowing Logic:

`avg(ask) over …` is replaced by `mavg(ask, 14)`

In ClickHouse, the expression `rows between 13 preceding and 0 following` implies a window size of 14. So in DolphinDB, the *window* parameter of the `mavg` function is set to 14.

The DolphinDB script can be written as follows:

```
select mavg(ask,14) from trade context by sym csort time
```